# How can I view/get scrapy POST/GET request headers

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I'd like to know if there's any method to view headers that are being sent when scrapy issues a POST/GET request within live logs, shell or by any other similar means. Thanks!

Comment: Did you check out the documentation?

Answer (score 14):

Both `Response` and `Request` objects will have their headers available via the `.headers` attribute.

Headers for both objects are modified via the Middleware between the Downloader and the Engine (see [Scrapy Architecture](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/architecture.html#architecture-overview)).  If you create a new `Request` object, it won't have any headers until it's passed through the Middleware that assigns them.

To view the request object, as it will be sent out, you will need to create a Middleware, put it closer to the Downloader than any other header-altering Middleware, and check the `request.headers` attribute at that time.

Alternatively, you can check out the headers of the request which returned a `Response` to the Spider by viewing the `response.request.headers`.  This may not be the `Request` object you sent out though, but the one that the resulted in the `Response` object that was returned (for instance, redirects/retries result in the originally dispatched `Request` object being different than the `Request` object in `response.request`).  Of course, this requires a `Response` object to have been returned to the spider, so it won't work for any `Request` that didn't generate a response (eg. DNS lookup error), or any `Response` that gets ignored or dropped via Middleware (eg. HTTP Status 400).

Answer (score -2):

when you make a request, you catch it on a callback method, the callback should be like:

```
def parse_method(self, response):
```

there you can check the response headers with `response.headers`

Comment: This solution is wrong because the OP has asked for Request Headers